# Chrome box shadow inconsistency

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In the screenshot below you can see two divs with a box shadow applied to both. The second one looks a bit different with a longer shadow and I'd like to figure out why. I'm trying to make it look the same as the first one.

The only difference between them is the border-radius. I'm using Chrome version 71.0.3578.98, on macOS 10.14.2. I tested with Safari and Firefox and don't see this problem.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { 
            background-color: #efefef;
        }
        div {
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
                        0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 
                        0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 16px;
            margin: 24px;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        div.one {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        }
        div.two {
            border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="one">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Curabitur convallis ut est at tristique.
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur convallis ut est at tristique.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

screenshot of box-shadow issue:

[image]

Comment: you found some edge cases I case, if you change any value with +/- 1px the shadow change

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but seem that it works.

```
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
                        0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 
                        0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```